# highlight multiple texts using conditional format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

As per the Question, I have a sheet here in that I am sending my inventories to several countries. but some countries am sending not. so can we highlight those countries using conditional formatting? I tried to do with the rule "Text contains" , but with that rule I can add only one country and I have to create more than 30 rules. can we highlight multiple texts using a rule.

pls take a look to the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10fxGKhiBwFfv1osdwTI3wu8i3knqmKQKHC8V1ffca5M/edit#gid=1146709446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to highlight different cells from a range, depending on whether they contain any of multiple country names: in this example that's `france`, `argentina` and `brazil`.

If that's the case, you can set `Format cells if...` to `Custom formula is`, and provide the following custom formula (considering that the range is `B2:B`):

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2,"france|argentina|brazil")
```

[image]
[image]

#### Update:

You can make the Regex case insensitive this way:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2,"(?i)france|argentina|brazil")
```

Comment: @lamblichus but one issue is there, it works only if it is lowercase. if u take a look to the sheet once more then there is shown.

Comment: @Lizi1990 I edited my answer to add the formula to make this case insensitive (add `(?i)`). See `Update` at the bottom. I hope this is helpful to you.